# Workgroup computer can access the folder and network drive of domain server?

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain

I have user that joined to domain and a workgroup computer.

However, when i map the network drive to the both computers of the user member of Domain and Workgroup, they have both access to the network drive and its folders.

I am just confused why is it that the workgroup computer can access the network drive of domain server (Windows Server 2003).

Comment: Did you map the drive and supply credentials on the workgroup computer?

Comment: hi. im sorry im a newbie. yes i try to map the drive to workgroup computer (just to test if the network drive of my Domain Servr is accessible only for domain user).... What do you mean by the supply credentials?

Comment: when you mapped the drive, did you put in a username and password?

Comment: yes. username and password of my domain server

Comment: That's why it can access it, you supplied domain credentials on the workgroup machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you supply domain credentials (username/password) when mapping the drive on the workgroup computer, it will authenticate with those credentials and allow access.